# Why are questions valid without question marks in speaking but not valid when writing?

Tags: punctuation

In the case where I have

What is the name of the fourth son.

Without a question mark "?" in speaking it is considered a question but in writing it is not.

Comment: Are you asking why people do not say, out loud, in conversation, things like "Where is your hat question mark", or "The house is on fire exclamation mark"? If so, consider research on the difference between spoken and written English.

Comment: Conversely people say something that sounds like a question but isn't, and would not contain an interrogative mark in writing. See [High rising terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_rising_terminal).

Comment: Yes, that is my question @Michael Harvey

Comment: Spoken English is not written English. Except in dictation, we do not speak punctuation such as commas, periods, question and exclamation marks.

Comment: Written English needs punctuation because it lacks the intonation of speech.

Comment: Therefore does writing the sentence "What Is the name of her fourth son" without a question mark make it a statement rather than a question?

Comment: 'Therefore' what? It is phrased as a a question. It starts 'What is...'. It requires a question mark. How could it be a statement?

Comment: Exactly, it can not be a statement just because the question mark was omitted. I am in an argument where my opponent says that "What is the name of her fourth son" is a statement without the question mark in writing. Therefore implying that her fourth son's name is "what", just like "James is the name of her fourth son". So as not to argue in the dark I am here to seek expert opinions.

Comment: **What is the name of her third son.**, in writing, is either a broken or wrongly written question, or a statement, as you say, that "What" is her son's name. The second interpretation is rather forced, as if we are considering an artificial example conccocted for the sake of an argument. Native speakers, knowing that 'What" is an extremely unlikely choice of name for a child, will prefer the first interpretation. Tell your opponent to stop being a dick. English (or any language) is not just word-Lego; common sense is involved.

Comment: What didn't make varsity this year, but [Who is first baseman](https://www.baseball-almanac.com/humor4.shtml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a question mark in speaking, so your question does not really make any sense.

In speaking, the sentences:

> What is the name of the fourth son.

and

> What is the name of the fourth son?

Can sound exactly the same, so this is technically ambiguous, but because of the initial "what" it is universally assumed to be a question, because leading interrogative words like "what" are one of the indicators that do exist in spoken English which can be used to indicate the presence of a question (when question marks aren't an option).

In writing, however, a question mark is required to form a grammatically correct question.  Writing simply has more indicators than speech does, and all of the indicators matter.  That's really all there is to it.

Note that this is not anything special about English.  Almost every language I'm aware of has more indicators when writing than when speaking...

I'm assuming that your dispute is stemming from the following joke/puzzle (or a variant of it):

> Someone's mother has four sons.
>   Three are named North, South, and East.
>   What is the name of the fourth son.

(And you're challenged to provide the name of the fourth son)

Note that this is really a "gotcha" sort of puzzle, so it's deliberately relying on rule technicalities to try to mislead people.  In real conversation, people don't generally do this, so your suggestion that this is "valid" is not really true for general speech/writing anyway (in the real world, most people would not consider this "valid", because it's deliberately misleading).  It's only really appropriate in the context of a puzzle where misdirection is supposed to be part of the point.